# Tabla horas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema al generar las horas en una tabla de JavaScript, utilizo un for para sumar las horas de dos en dos pero no me suma nada, se repite el mismo número una y otra vez, y otro problema sería como escribir los días de la semana en la fila superior de la tabla.

Así es como quiero desarollar la tabla, pero no se si estoy desarrollando bien la tabla para poder hacer esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function genera_tabla() {
 
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tabla = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
 
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
 
 var a;  
 // Imprime las horas. 
 for (a = 0; a < 8; a = a+2){
 hilera.textContent = a;
 }
  
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      let elmt = (j == 0 || i == 0) ? "th" : "td";
      var celda = document.createElement(elmt);
      var textoCelda = "fila " + i + ", columna " + j + "\n";
      celda.textContent = textoCelda;
      hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }

    tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
  }

  tabla.appendChild(tblBody);

  body.appendChild(tabla);

  tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<html>
 
<input type="button" value="Genera una tabla" onclick="genera_tabla()">
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que hay ya una respuesta. Como que ya lo hice pongo también mi respuesta

```js
var diasDeLaSemena = ["", "Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves", "viernes"]
var entreHorras = ["","9:00 - 11:00","11:00 - 13:00","13:00 - 15:00"];



function genera_tabla() {
 
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tabla = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
  
  var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
   for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {   
     textoCelda = diasDeLaSemena[j];
     var celda = document.createElement("th");
     celda.textContent = textoCelda;
     hilera.appendChild(celda);
   }
 tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
 
  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    var elmt,textoCelda;
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
       if(j==0){elmt = "th";
       textoCelda = entreHorras[i];
       }else{elmt = "td";
            textoCelda = ""}
       var celda = document.createElement(elmt);
      
      celda.textContent = textoCelda;
      hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }

    tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
  }

  tabla.appendChild(tblBody);

  body.appendChild(tabla);

  tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Genera una tabla" onclick="genera_tabla()">
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tienes en el `for` donde imprimes la hora, yo lo reemplace por una variable llamada **hora** que la inicializo en 9 y esta afuera del primer `for`, luego le voy sumando dos (2) a medida que va armando cada fila así:

```js
function genera_tabla() {
 
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tabla = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
 
  var hora = 9;
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var hilera = document.createElement("tr");
  
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      let elmt = (j == 0 || i == 0) ? "th" : "td";
      var celda = document.createElement(elmt);
      if(i > 0 && j == 0){
        var proximaHora = (hora + 2);
        var textoCelda = hora+":00 - "+proximaHora+":00";
        hora = proximaHora;
      }else{
        var textoCelda = "fila " + i + ", columna " + j + "\n";
      }
      celda.textContent = textoCelda;
      hilera.appendChild(celda);
    }

    tblBody.appendChild(hilera);
  }

  tabla.appendChild(tblBody);

  body.appendChild(tabla);

  tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Genera una tabla" onclick="genera_tabla()">
```

Espero que sea lo que andas buscando